# Python check for primality golfing

Tags: python

So far I have come up with

```
isPrime = lambda i: all(i % x for x in range(2, i)) and i > 1
```

I am trying to accomplish this in the shortest number of character whitespace is not counted looking for any insights or tweaks to help me out.

I didn't feel it was appropriate to end up on the code golf site as this is not a proposed challenge but If I am mistaken I will move it

Comment: You should switch the order of your conditions, `i > 1` should go first so it can short circuit

Comment: food for thought: not re.match(r'^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$', '1' * n)